# Populating a two dimensional array is adding a new element instead of a row

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a large tab delimited text file that I need to parse.

This is a sample of the data as it looks in notepad++:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ParsePriceFile()
{
  var priceFile = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.WatchDirectory, Settings.Default.CustomerPricingDataFile);

  var priceFileList = new List<string>();
  
  foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(priceFile))
  {
    priceFileList.AddRange(line.Split('\t'));
  }

  return priceFileList;
}
```

I'm ending up with these results though:

[image]

I can just count each element and reference it with the appropriate index but I thought I could make a 2d array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined `priceFileList` to be a list of string.  Why would you think it should be a 2d array?

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks for the feedback! How do I add those to the array, as another array inside of it?

Comment: You can use a `List<string[]>`, but you probably want a `List<class>`. Or [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: Post shows ZERO 2d or jagged arrays, so very unclear how title is related to the body. Please [edit] to align. Note that writing your own code to parse  CSV is not a best way to spend ones time - use existing libraries to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new List<string[]>()` and then add each entire array to it:

```
var priceFileList = new List<string[]>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(priceFile))
{
    priceFileList.Add(line.Split('\t'));
}
```

The result is not literally a 2D array, but a List of 1D arrays instead. For many purposes this will not make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AddRange on a List, which simply adds the IEnumerable passed in to the end of the list.  If you want two values for each item, you'll have to make your List something that will hold that, like a Dictionary<string, string> or a List<<Tuple<string, string>

```
var priceFileList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  
  foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(priceFile))
  {
    priceFileList.Add(line.Split('\t')[0], line.Split('\t')[1]);
  }
```